# How can I get this to print to my file instead of the screen in my Perl program?

Tags: perl

I am using the following example from [Lingua::StopWords](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua%3a%3aStopWords):

```
use Lingua::StopWords qw( getStopWords );
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');

my @words = qw( i am the walrus goo goo g'joob );

# prints "walrus goo goo g'joob"
print join ' ', grep { !$stopwords->{$_} } @words;
```

How do I get it to use my `$document`, remove stopwords and print the results to a file? See my code here:

```
open(FILESOURCE, "sample.txt") or die("Unable to open requested file.");
my $document = <FILESOURCE>;
close (FILESOURCE);

open(TEST, "results_stopwords.txt") or die("Unable to open requested file.");

use Lingua::StopWords qw( getStopWords );
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');

print join ' ', grep { !$stopwords->{$_} } $document;
```

I tried these variations:

```
print join ' ', grep { !$stopwords->{$_} } TEST;


print TEST join ' ', grep { !$stopwords->{$_} } @words;
```

Basically, how do I read in a document, remove the stop words and then write the result to a new file?

Comment: You need to open the file for writing.  Use warnings and check that print succeeds, and you will see that (eg, print ... or die...).  And please, please, please put file names and $! in your error messages.

Comment: What’s wrong with shell redirection? That’s the normal way to do these sorts of things. It probably doesn’t make sense to hardcode the paths of input and output in the program. That’s what stdin (or ARGV) and stdout are for.

Comment: Don't forget to close the file and check if it succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, you forgot to tokenise the input text into words. A simplistic alternative to `Lingua::EN::Splitter::words` is to [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) a line on spaces into a list of words (approximately).

Taking [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)'s comment in account, this program is fit to be a Unix filter.

```
use strictures;
use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);
use Lingua::EN::Splitter qw(words);
my $stopwords = getStopWords('en');
while (defined(my $line = <>)) {
    print join ' ', grep { !$stopwords->{$_} } @{ words $line };
}
```

Comment: Our edits overlapped. Let's better keep it this way, the compiler optimisation is recent-ish and does not cover more complicated expressions; I want to have code that's robust against copy-paste programming.